# How to get array from JSON data and convert it into desired new array format?

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array, key-value

I'm getting following JSON request data :

```
data = "{\"photo\":[{\"fileURL\":\"https:\\/\\/www.filepicker.io\\/api\\/file\\/RqAN2jZ7ScC8eOx6ckUE\",\"filename\":\"IMG_0003.JPG\"},{\"fileURL\":\"https:\\/\\/www.filepicker.io\\/api\\/file\\/XdwtFsu6RLaoZurZXPug\",\"filename\":\"IMG_0004.JPG\"}]}";
```

I want to make an array from the above JSON data into following format :

```
Array
(
    [vshare] => Array
        (
            [IMG_0003.JPG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/RqAN2jZ7ScC8eOx6ckUE
                )

            [IMG_0004.JPG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XdwtFsu6RLaoZurZXPug
                )

        )

)
```

The actual JSON request data could be huge in size. For your reference I've used only two such elements into it.

So can someone please help me in providing me the way to achieve the desired new array in an efficient way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you getting this JSON? Are you calling an API? Do you have control over it?

Comment: @amrhady:It's coming in a request from mobile app. But that's not the issue now. My issue and challenge is how to create a new array in desired format in an robust and efficient way?

Comment: My point is that if you have control over the data being posted to you, change it's structure to fit your needs. Instead of having to process it on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
<?php
$data = "{\"photo\":[{\"fileURL\":\"https:\\/\\/www.filepicker.io\\/api\\/file\\/RqAN2jZ7ScC8eOx6ckUE\",\"filename\":\"IMG_0003.JPG\"},{\"fileURL\":\"https:\\/\\/www.filepicker.io\\/api\\/file\\/XdwtFsu6RLaoZurZXPug\",\"filename\":\"IMG_0004.JPG\"}]}";

$obj = json_decode($data);

$new_ar = array();
foreach ( $obj->photo as $photo ) {
    $new_ar['vshare'][$photo->filename] = array($photo->fileURL);
}
print_r($new_ar);
```

Should generate

```
Array
(
    [vshare] => Array
        (
            [IMG_0003.JPG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/RqAN2jZ7ScC8eOx6ckUE
                )

            [IMG_0004.JPG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XdwtFsu6RLaoZurZXPug
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

$data = json_decode($data,true);

OK TRY THIS THEN:

```
$data = "{\"photo\":[{\"fileURL\":\"https:\\/\\/www.filepicker.io\\/api\\/file\\/RqAN2jZ7ScC8eOx6ckUE\",\"filename\":\"IMG_0003.JPG\"},{\"fileURL\":\"https:\\/\\/www.filepicker.io\\/api\\/file\\/XdwtFsu6RLaoZurZXPug\",\"filename\":\"IMG_0004.JPG\"}]}";
$data = json_decode($data,true);
$NewData = false;
foreach($data['photo'] as $k=>$d){
    $NewData['vshare'][$d['filename']][] = $d['fileURL'];
}
var_dump($NewData);
```

Comment: how is that poor at all? lawl! 
it is the fastest way to convert json data to an array.
Exactly what he needed.

Comment: But I need further new array in desired format. That's the main challenge and issue I'm facing right now.

Comment: This wouldn't give him the array he wants.